# Retrieve HyperLink NavigateUrl value from GridView Row

Tags: c#, asp.net

My GridView is as following has one column Training Details with HyperLink

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTrainingItems" runat="server"....
......
......
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Training Details" HeaderStyle-Wrap="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkTrainingItemDetails" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#"~/TrainingItemDetails.aspx?ItemId=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"itemId").ToString().Trim() + "&EmpId=" + Request.QueryString["EmpId"].ToString() %>'
        Name='link' CssClass="btn btn-info" Target="_blank">View</asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
</asp:TemplateField>
....
```

Right now I am confused on how to get the NagivateUrl value from this GridViewRow?

I have tried something like

```
GridViewRow row = gvTrainingItemsPending.Rows[e.RowIndex];
.....
((HyperLink) row.Cells[10].Controls[0]).NavigateUrl
```

but it returns the following error. Can I get some help? Thanks!

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink'.

Comment: It seems that the first control in cell 10 of the row is not a HyperLink. This would suggest you have the wrong cell. Furtermore your GridView is `gvTrainingItems` while the code looks in `gvTrainingItemsPending`

Comment: uh...I was looking at the wrong GridView thus counting the incorrect cell number. Really dumb mistake :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using the `FindControl` method to pull this out. This will pull out the control regardless of the cell in the row.

```
GridViewRow row = gvTrainingItems.Rows[e.RowIndex];
.....
string url = ((HyperLink) row.FindControl("lnkTrainingItemDetails")).NavigateUrl;
```

Comment: WOW i didn't know this exist. I will take advantage of this tool next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the incorrect GridView thus the cell number is incorrect, also it is controls[1] in my case. The syntax is correct tho.

Answer (score 0):

Use findcontrol method for getting control id and its value.